# How to map struct members to a string?

Tags: c++, c++11

In my project, I've to call a 3rd party API which will give the result in the form of a struct (example below).

```
typedef struct _innerTest
{
    int Status1;
    bool Status2;
    std::vector<int> Status3;
}InnerTest;

typedef struct _test 
{
    int Status1;
    bool Status2;
    InnerTest InnerStatus;
}Test;
```

Once I get the results, I have to set these values internally. Each value in the struct will be mapped to a certain string (these strings are required to update the values internally). For example the mapping can be something like below:

```
Test.Status1                <-->    Status1
Test.Status2                <-->    Status2
Test.InnerStatus.Status1    <-->    Status3
Test.InnerStatus.Status2    <-->    Status4
Test.InnerStatus.Status3[0] <-->    Status5
Test.InnerStatus.Status3[1] <-->    Status6
```

What would be the best approach to maintain the mapping information. Note that the size of vector inside the structure can vary. If new status is added for example, I want to just add the mapping information is some xml/config file and the code should work without any changes. I just want some pointers to go forward. (Just FYI, I'm okay with using boost libraries if necessary).

I've tried to explain my problem as simple as possible. Please ask me in comments if more details is required.

**@edited1**

I can save the above proposed mapping information in my internal DB. But, after that how can I map for example, `Test.Status1` should take value form `test.Status1` (struct variable).

**@edited2**

In my case there are around 60 status items. So, I don't want to write `if/switch` statement to read from `struct`. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178327/discussion-between-swamy-and-mfromla).